# Is there an algorithm for merging elements of an array of objects with the same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm

I have the following data, and I've been looking for a reference to an algorithm for building a returned array that is grouped by a field (e.g. discipline) and pushes in all the unique fields.

Initial Dataset:

```
[      
      { discipline: 1, originalBudgetDollars: 1114.96 },
      { discipline: 2, originalBudgetDollars: 192 },
      { discipline: 1, expendedDollars: 1137.24 },
      { discipline: 2, expendedDollars: 55.08 },
      { discipline: 1, forecastAtCompletionDollars: 1276.62 },
      { discipline: 2, forecastAtCompletionDollars: 96 },
      { discipline: 1, earnedValueDollars: 81.6 },
      { discipline: 2, earnedValueDollars: 10636.6 }
]
```

Desired Result:

```
[ 
      { discipline: 1, originalBudgetDollars: 1114.96, expendedDollars: 1137.24, remainingDollars: -22.28, forecastAtCompletionDollars: 1276.62, earnedValueDollars: 81.6 },
      { discipline: 2, originalBudgetDollars: 192, expendedDollars: 55.08,  remainingDollars: 136.92, forecastAtCompletionDollars: 96, earnedValueDollars: 10636.6 },
]
```

Comment: Do you want to get the result in an object or in an array?

Comment: Where does `remainingDollars` comes from?

Comment: remainingDollars = originalBudgetDollars - expendedDollars

Comment: the original data is an array of objects, would like the same for the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular algorithm for this problem, what you can do is break this problem into subproblem and get the desired results. The below snippet will also work if in the future you gonna add `discipline: 3` data but there must be `originalBudgetDollars` and `expendedDollars` fields in the object (so that we can calculate `remainingDollars`).

Here I've used [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const data = [
  { discipline: 1, originalBudgetDollars: 1114.96 },
  { discipline: 2, originalBudgetDollars: 192 },
  { discipline: 1, expendedDollars: 1137.24 },
  { discipline: 2, expendedDollars: 55.08 },
  { discipline: 1, forecastAtCompletionDollars: 1276.62 },
  { discipline: 2, forecastAtCompletionDollars: 96 },
  { discipline: 1, earnedValueDollars: 81.6 },
  { discipline: 2, earnedValueDollars: 10636.6 },
];

const obj = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { discipline } = curr;
  acc[discipline] = Object.assign(acc[discipline] ?? {}, curr);
  return acc;
}, {});

// Get only values of an object
const result = Object.values(obj);

// Adding remainingDollars in all object
result.forEach((obj) => {
  obj.remainingDollars = (
    obj.originalBudgetDollars - obj.expendedDollars
  ).toFixed(2);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the references!